# Are the flag reasons sometimes truncated in moderation pop-up?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, flagging

I was reviewing [this item](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658042/probability-of-hospitalized-population/658054#658054), and it seemed to me that at one point the list of possible flag reasons came up without "very low quality" appearing, both in the queue and on the Question/Answer itself (flag link), but a couple of minutes later the pop-up did show that choice.

I'm inclined to think this might be an HTML fetch/timing problem, but previously I thought there might be some logic behind the truncated flag reason lists I saw occasionally.  Here I persisted because the Answer had an automated low-quality score, and it seemed a natural option based on ambiguity of content.

Answer (score 3):

In short, yes.  For the "very low quality" option, it is only present when the post in question has a non-positive score (see [this MSO post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93606/214632)).  So if the upvote appeared before the downvote, in that interval the "very low quality" option would not be present.

[This meta.MO post](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1175/13653) gives some more information (though not much more).

Comment: That's awesome by way of explanation, because I'd just placed a downvote.  Dots connected!

Comment: @hardmath: Well, that's one SE mystery is no longer unsolved! (I guess this sort of information should be more easily accessible.)

Comment: Heh, I'll have to get you to put "status by design" on this Q.